# rbind (concatenate) several big files

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, bigdata

I have some problems regarding Project **R** and merging tab-delimited files. 
I guess my biggest problem is that we are talking about 165 files with a size of around 180MB.

For sure I work on an Ubuntu server after my local OSX computer was not able to handle the data.

I tried several methods as outline here:

So we are talking about the "lapply method", the "plyr" method, a for-loop solution and a newer method with the fread-function.

Nevertheless it's not possible to merge all these csv files into one data.frame.

```
require(data.table)
require(bit64)
require(plyr)
setwd("~/Documents/Data/App/feed/")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options(scipen = 999)

# List of all the contained files
file_list <- list.files()

#FREAD-Method
dataset = rbindlist(lapply(file_list, fread, header=FALSE, sep="\t"))

# LAPPLY-Method
dataset2 <- do.call("rbind",lapply(file_list, FUN=function(files){read.table(files, header=TRUE, sep="\t")}))


#LDPLY-Method
dataset3 <- ldply(file_list, read.table, header=FALSE, sep="\t", .progress = "text", .inform = TRUE)
```

I guess the For-Loop-solution is not so fancy.

Now my big question: How can I merge my (big) CSV files in one data.frame? Or is **R** not able to handle such big data?

Would be happy if anybody can help me out since I tried to find the solution with several parameters for 2 days now.

Comment: Just use linux `cat` command, you don't even have headers to worry about.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113715 , then keep the data in the database, access as needed from R.

Comment: Wow... OK, sounds easy. But is it possible to do something like a loop for all files?

Comment: "165 files with a size of around 180MB" - do you mean each is 180MB or in total? It all comes down to memory.

Comment: Just a notice: My csv files have no ".csv" in the filename. So I have to rename all files?      @zx8754: yes... each file is around 200MB. But the server has 128GB RAM... So I thought this would be no problem

Comment: No need to rename, `cat * > ../result.txt`

Comment: OK, the cat-method worked out. Thanks. Nevertheless I have the problem to import the data to R for upcoming statistics. Is there any smooth way? I know: We need a data base and we are setting this up at the moment. Nevertheless we have some ad-hoc analysis to do....

Comment: Do you really need every row and every column of the data for analysis? Subset outside R, then `fread` subsetted files into R for analysis.

Comment: Sadly I need all rows since we are talking about time-resolved data